# Open camera from foreground service which was started in background on Android 11

Tags: android, android-service, android-camera, foreground-service, android-11

Based on https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restriction-exemptions we can only start using camera in foreground service without launching app (making it visible) if:

- The service is started by a system component.
- The service is started by interacting with app widgets.
- The service is started by interacting with a notification.
- The service is started as a PendingIntent that is sent from a different, visible app.
- The service is started by an app that is a device policy controller that is running in device owner mode.
- The service is started by an app which provides the VoiceInteractionService.
- The service is started by an app that has the START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND privileged permission.

In my case I need to open camera in background without user interaction and when screen of device is off, in such case as I understand it's possible only with:

- The service is started by a system component.
- The service is started by an app that is a device policy controller that is running in device owner mode.
- The service is started by an app that has the START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND privileged permission.

System component - though this one I guess also isn't not for developers, because it means a system app - system component?

And also what about `START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND`, can a regular application have this permission, how to grant it? Can't find any info about this one on Android site

If it's also only for system apps then the only choice is device policy controller to open camera from foreground service which is started in background on Android 11+?

p.s. if anyone is interested why such functionality may be needed. It's needed for dashboard camera apps. Users have a smartphone in their cars and when they for example turn on the phone (if it wasn't powered) they want video recording to be started automatically without their interaction.

So it would start recording automatically in all cases like a real dashcam device

But Android 11 brings these limitations...

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer seems possible in Android 11 and up (for very good reasons!). What is possible is as soon as the device connects to a carkit or car radio (via Bluetooth, you can register a BroadcastReceiver that listens to intents with action `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED`), you post a local notification. The user can launch the foreground service then by interacting with the notification.